# Parsing a Very Simply Config File

Tags: c++, configuration, config, configuration-files, obd-ii

I am writing a OBDII reading library / application in C++.  Data is retrieved from the car's computer by sending a simple string command, then passing the result through a function specific to each parameter.

I would like to read a config file of all the commands I want, something like this perhaps:

```
Name, Command, function

Engine RPM, 010C, ((256*A)+B)/4
Speed, 010D, A
```

Basically, very simple, all data needs to just be read in as a string. Can anyone recommend a good simple library for this?  My target is g++ and/ or Clang on Linux if that matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use **std::ifstream** to read *line by line*, and **boost::split** to split the line by `,`.

Sample code:

You could check tokens size for sanity checks of file loaded.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/split.hpp>
#include <boost/algorithm/string/classification.hpp>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::ifstream ifs("e:\\save.txt");

    std::string line;
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    while (std::getline(ifs, line)) {
        boost::split(tokens, line, boost::is_any_of(","));
        if (line.empty())
            continue;

        for (const auto& t : tokens) {
            std::cout << t << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You could also use [String Toolkit Library](http://www.partow.net/programming/strtk/index.html) if you don't want to implemented. [Docs](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23198/C-String-Toolkit-StrTk-Tokenizer)

Comment: That seems like it might work.  My thinking was that a dedicated config reading library would be best, but is that not likely to be the case when my data is so simple?