# Reading information from a text file and properly storing it in arrays, int

Tags: c++, arrays, file, file-io, fstream

I would like to have a piece of C++ code that reads from a text file and saves the information in some variables, arrays...

For example, let's say we have a file Numbers.txt, which contains 4 integers. An example  code that I found so far ( and does not do the trick for me ) looks like this :

```
string weight, height, width, depth;
ifstream MyFile("Numbers.txt");
MyFile >> weight;
MyFile >> height;
MyFile >> width;
MyFile >> depth;
```

But it only reads single pieces of data, separated by an empty space.

I would like code to be able to read several pieces of data that can be in a same row. To clarify, that's an example of how a text file format would look like...

```
FileName
ProjectName
Names
IDs
```

and en example of actual content of a text file ...

```
// SomeData.txt 
FileName: SomeData.txt
ProjectName: Second Attempt // should be able to read with spaces too, and save in a string as "Second Attempt" 
Names: John, Frank, Mike // I guess it could be without commas too
IDs: 42, 505, 1591, 4358, 12, 743
```

So the main problem is for the program to skip to next lines while reading, and ignoring "keywords" like "Names:", "IDs"... and at the same time be ready to read as many entries as there are in a line, even if there is no information in advance of  how many there would be.

The information just read would best be saved as such:

```
FileName -> string
ProjectName -> string
Names -> array of strings
IDs -> array of integers
```

How would an example of such code look like ?

Comment: Read in data from the line until you reach a new line, each piece of data being separated by a comma or a space. This can be done by using a loop, with the condition that "while the input is not equal to the end line character" and the event "put data into the array, separated by a comma" If you want to use an outside library as @NetVipeC pointed out you can use boost. It's relatively easy to create your own `split` function, though.

Comment: You could [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24918394/parsing-a-very-simply-config-file/24918887#24918887) related question. Summary: using `std::getline` to read line by line and `boost::split` to split the line by separators. In this case you could split by `:` and later the second string by `,`.

Comment: There are sooooo many examples of reading data from a text file, you should search first before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is incomplete but here's an overview of how I would go about this:

When you are using an `ifstream` you can grab the whole line at once using a function called [getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/getline/) and store it in a `char` array.

You could then use a function such as `strtok` to split that line up, as I notice that the data comes after a `:` character.

At this point you could have a `switch` statement depending on the string before the `:`, and process your data appropriately. For example if you have `IDs` then use atoi to convert them to `ints` and store them in arrays etc.